# Failed to enroll admin user : Error: Calling enroll endpoint failed with error [Error: socket hang up]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am facing a problem when I try to run the application in the Hyperledger Fabric 2.3 version.
Reference Link: [hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs/test-network/2.3](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/test_network.html)

- commands

```
$ ./network.sh up createChannel    
$ ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript/ -ccl javascript   
$ node app.js
```

I successfully create the channel and even deploy the chaincode in javascript, With 2 organizations and 2 peers under each organization and 2 users: admin and user1.

Ubuntu Version: 18.04
Fabric Version: 2.3.x

[image: ErrorImage]

Can anyone please answer this question?

Comment: I will go over two things first. First. The `2.2 documentation` is referenced in `2.3 code`. Not a big deal, but match the version. Second. Looking at your log, `./network.sh up createChannel` did not work properly. Is it correct that you did it right?

Comment: Also, as a comment on the question itself, if the error log can be expressed in text format, it should be written in text. Not an image. See the link below.[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your command, an error occurred in the process of enrolling the admin client.
this process is a command that requests `enroll` from Fabric-CA, and Fabric-CA must be up.

However, in the case of the command `./network.sh up createChannel` you entered, Fabric-CA is not up.
You need to add a parameter option to up Fabric-CA.

See the command usage for `./network.sh`

- https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/test_network.html

```
Usage:
  network.sh <Mode> [Flags]
    Modes:
      up - Bring up Fabric orderer and peer nodes. No channel is created
      up createChannel - Bring up fabric network with one channel
      createChannel - Create and join a channel after the network is created
      deployCC - Deploy a chaincode to a channel (defaults to asset-transfer-basic)
      down - Bring down the network

    Flags:
    Used with network.sh up, network.sh createChannel:
    -ca <use CAs> -  Use Certificate Authorities to generate network crypto material
    -c <channel name> - Name of channel to create (defaults to "mychannel")
    -s <dbtype> - Peer state database to deploy: goleveldb (default) or couchdb
    -r <max retry> - CLI times out after certain number of attempts (defaults to 5)
    -d <delay> - CLI delays for a certain number of seconds (defaults to 3)
    -i <imagetag> - Docker image tag of Fabric to deploy (defaults to "latest")
    -cai <ca_imagetag> - Docker image tag of Fabric CA to deploy (defaults to "latest")
    -verbose - Verbose mode

    Used with network.sh deployCC
    -c <channel name> - Name of channel to deploy chaincode to
    -ccn <name> - Chaincode name.
    -ccl <language> - Programming language of the chaincode to deploy: go (default), java, javascript, typescript
    -ccv <version>  - Chaincode version. 1.0 (default), v2, version3.x, etc
    -ccs <sequence>  - Chaincode definition sequence. Must be an integer, 1 (default), 2, 3, etc
    -ccp <path>  - File path to the chaincode.
    -ccep <policy>  - (Optional) Chaincode endorsement policy using signature policy syntax. The default policy requires an endorsement from Org1 and Org2
    -cccg <collection-config>  - (Optional) File path to private data collections configuration file
    -cci <fcn name>  - (Optional) Name of chaincode initialization function. When a function is provided, the execution of init will be requested and the function will be invoked.

    -h - Print this message

 Possible Mode and flag combinations
   up -ca -r -d -s -i -cai -verbose
   up createChannel -ca -c -r -d -s -i -cai -verbose
   createChannel -c -r -d -verbose
   deployCC -ccn -ccl -ccv -ccs -ccp -cci -r -d -verbose

 Examples:
   network.sh up createChannel -ca -c mychannel -s couchdb -i 2.0.0
   network.sh createChannel -c channelName
   network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript/ -ccl javascript
   network.sh deployCC -ccn mychaincode -ccp ./user/mychaincode -ccv 1 -ccl javascript
```

---

so, try build a test network with the command below

```
./network.sh up createChannel -ca
```